# Is it possible to build up a system based only on individual markers without postGIS?

Tags: postgis, leaflet, react

We are a team of 2 developers and we've been thinking this month on how to build up a system for showing locations on a map. After reading some articles and taking some courses seems like the best aproach would be PostGIS for saving the data.

First some background. We have 2 months to build a demo and the stack looks as follows:

- ReactJS
- Leaflet
- PostgreSQL
- Node

Since we only need to show certain locations on maps, seems like geometries are not neccesary. So the way that we would save the location would be just LatLng and the object itself (user, place, etc...) in standard tables. Distances would be calculated by leaflet if neccesary. Tiles would be provided by CartoDB.We would build a simple function to translate the data to geoJSON before passing it to leaflet.

My question is:

- Should I consider PostGIS or just standard SQL table structure?

We seek any suggestion or corrections since this is our first app with gis data.

Comment: PostGIS is a PostresQLS extension, not a DB of its own

Comment: Good to know! Do you still think I could need it? Does the structure I said for saving locations sound vague and not enough?

Comment: I´d say this depends largely on the project size; for instance, how many locations are we talking about? how frequently will those be updated? setting up and managing a full scale RDBMS for static data equivalent to a 1Mb geojson would be a little overkill. the need to update those hourly could be a reason though, as would be the need to selectively display the map extend's worth of points out of 2 million locations...

Comment: The project will have 3 types of locations. Each will average:
- People: 500.000 to 1.500.000
- Places: 100.000
- Ads: 10.000
These numbers refer to a whole country and would stay like this for at least 2 years. loading a sector of it would load 1000 at the most and would need to make calls to the server if the user moves more than 100kms from the last loading point.

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.